# What is the difference between simulation mode and test mode in Canoe

Tags: capl, canoe

I just want to know what is the difference between simulation mode and test mode in Canoe and how it makes difference when writing CAPL scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In test mode you have the real ECU in as a node, in that case you need the corresponding DBC file,  in simulation mode you dont have a ECU.

Comment: yes thats true but what difference it makes to capl scripting ?any comments ?